# How to insert records from staging table to master table and update records as sync status true

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables (1. Staging Table and 2. Master Table).

### Staging Table (temp_Customer).

[image: Staging Table]

---

**Master Table (Customer_Master)**

[image: Master Table]

I want to insert records from Staging table to Master table one by one and update those records as sync_status = 1 in the staging table.So that next time I would be able to know that which records are not in my master table and I will pick only those records where sync_status is 0.

My boss has suggested me to do it with loop but not to use it with the curser.
and I don't know how to use loops in sql..

Comment: Are you using MySQL, SQL Server, or something else?  They are not all the same thing.

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: it would be great for me  if i can get answer for both ms sql and mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using a transaction which will first attempt to insert all records from staging into master, and then will mark the staging records as having been transferred.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [yourTransaction]

    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO Master ([STK_Code], [Cust_Code], [Cust_Add], ...) -- other columns
        SELECT [STK_Code], [Cust_Code], [Cust_Add], ...
        FROM Staging
        WHERE sync_status = 0

        UPDATE Staging
        SET sync_status = 1
        WHERE sync_status = 0

        COMMIT TRANSACTION [yourTransaction]

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]

  END CATCH
```

Comment: Hi @Tim,

Can't we do it using loop?

Comment: In general, you should avoid loops in SQL unless there is a good reason to use them.  Most SQL operations are set based, and designed to operate on entire tables.